# how to process in parallel and synchronously in spring integration?

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, ftp, spring-integration

Is it possible in Spring integration to keep the channels synchronous (get acknowledgement after sending the message) but process more messages at the same time (process in parallel) without creating own code with threads (i.e. ExecutorService execute and submit worker) and awaiting on them? I would like to upload files through FTP using  but uploading more at the same time without creating own threads in the code. I need to know when all files are uploaded (that is why I want it to be synchronous). Is it possible via Spring integration configuration and, if so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, looks like you need some flow like:

1. `<gateway>` to send files to the channel and wait some result as acknowledgement
2. `<splitter>` to an `ExecutorChannel` to process each file in parallel
3. `<int-ftp:outbound-gateway>` to upload each file
4. `<aggregator>` to correlate and group results of `<int-ftp:outbound-gateway>`
5. `<aggregator>` should send its result to the `<gateway>`, which is waitng at that time.

Let me know, if something isn't clear.

**UPDATE**

> How to do this in Spring Integration Java DSL any examples?

Something like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableIntegration
@IntegrationComponentScan
public class Configuration {

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow uploadFiles() {
        return f ->
                   f.split()
                       .handle(Ftp.outboundGateway(this.ftpSessionFactory,
                           AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.Command.PUT, "'remoteDirectory'"))
                       .aggregate();
    }

}

@MessagingGateway(defaultRequestChannel = "uploadFiles.input") 
interface FtpUploadGateway {

    List<String> upload(List<File> filesToUpload);

}
```

Comment: How to do this in Spring Integration Java DSL any examples?

Comment: right now this is my flow dsl   IntegrationFlows.from(Sftp.inboundAdapter(getSftpSessionFactory())
       .temporaryFileSuffix("COPY")
       .localDirectory(directory)
       .deleteRemoteFiles(false)
       .preserveTimestamp(true)
       .remoteDirectory("remoteDir"))
       .patternFilter(env.getProperty("*.txt")), e -> e.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(500).maxMessagesPerPoll(5)))
       .handle("mybean", "myMethod")
       .handle(Files.outboundAdapter(new File("success")))   
       .deleteSourceFiles(true)
       .autoCreateDirectory(true))
       .get();

Comment: Sorry, it's difficult to read code from the comments. Consider to raise a new SO question and will discuss there.

Comment: Posted a new question .My bad SO comments does not have formatting http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35951472/need-to-process-multiple-files-in-parallel-in-spring-integration

Comment: @ArtemBilan in your DSL example, after `f.split()`, is the rest handled in parallel ? I would expect it needs a `.channel(c -> c.execute(executorService))` or something of sorts. When I add this, the flow exits immediately and doesn't wait for the responses to aggregate.

Comment: Yes, I missed that part . Indeed an `ExecutorChannel` must be there after splitter to process in parallel. “The flow exits” is to vague. We need to understand how you send messages to this flow. Probably deserves its own SO thread

Answer (score 2):

This is very much possible in Spring by making use of `@Async` task processing.

First create a service which will perform the task asynchronously. Here make note of the `@Async` annotation, on `performTask` method, which will be scanned and marked by spring for asynchronous execution.

```
import java.util.concurrent.Future;

import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Async;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.AsyncResult;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class AsyncTask {

    @Async
    public Future<Result> performTask(String someArgument) {
        // put the business logic here and collect the result below
        Result result = new Result(); // this is some custom bean holding your result
        return new AsyncResult<Result>(result);
    }
}
```

Next create a component (*optional - can be from any other existing service as well*) which will invoke the above service.

```
import java.util.concurrent.Future;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class AsyncClass {

    @Autowired
    private AsyncTask asyncTask;

    public void doAsyncOperation() throws Exception {

    List<Future<Result>> futures = new ArrayList<Future<Result>>();

    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
        // Simulate multiple calls
        Future<Result > future = doAsync(String.valueOf(i));            
        futures.add(future);
    }

    for (Future<Result > future : futures) {
            // fetch the result
            Result result = future.get();
            // process the result
    }
}

    private Future<Result> doAsync(final String someArgument) {

        // this will immediately return with a placeholder Future object which
        // can be used later to fetch the result
        Future<Result> future = asyncTask.performAsync(someArgument);
        return future;
    }
}
```

The sample xml configuration required to enable async is as below (*For annotation based config use @EnableAsync*)

```
<task:annotation-driven executor="myExecutor" />
<task:executor id="myExecutor" pool-size="30" rejection-policy="CALLER_RUNS"/>
```

For detailed documentation refer  [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html#scheduling-annotation-support-async)