# How do I implement Multi Threading concept using Spring?

Tags: multithreading, spring

I have to process the huge no of records in a file.So i will be diving like FileDetailsReading (First Step),Validation of Records(Second Step) then processing of records(Thirdstept. 
This we need to implement using multi threading concepts using spring frame work.

Idea is One Thread from FirstThread Group will process First Step, Then a Thread from SecondThread Group will process the Second Step ,then a Thread from ThirdGroup will do the last task.

So once a thread completes a task in the ThreadGroup, another thread will do another step.

Any suggestions please to implement this scenario which is very helpful to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `@Async`available in Spring.
 Please consult  [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25742301/1910582) for guidelines on how to implement it.