# How to read and process multiple files concurrently in spring?

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-integration

I am new to Spring framework and I am doing one simple project using spring and got stuck in between.
In my project I am reading the file from directory using spring poller. And then processing that file through various channels and sending it to the queue. But problem is that "file-inbound-channel-adapter" (which I'm using ) is reading only one file at a time.
So I need a solution which will read and process multiple files at a time.
Is there any way to implement multithreading in spring integration.
Thank you.

Comment: hope [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25742319/1910582) helps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a `task-executor` to the poller; see [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#async-polling).

You can control the concurrency with `max-messages-per-poll` and the task executor's pool size. See the [complete poller configuration details](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#endpoint-namespace) for more information.

Comment: @Garry Russell...thank you,
With task-executor i'm able to poll multiple files but is there any way of polling multiple directories at a time or I've to create inbound-channel for each directory I'm going to poll ?

Comment: You currently need an inbound adapter for each directory. In 4.2, we introduced [conditional pollers](https://spring.io/blog/2015/05/28/spring-integration-4-2-milestone-1-is-available) which would enable you to change the directory on each poll (auto-create directory won't work for that, though).

Comment: ..I have to use separate inbound-channel-adapter for each directory as we are not planning to upgrade to 4.2 but thank you very much will be looking ahead of using it in my further projects.